# How to run code, that normally runs in a rule, on a selected item?

Tags: vba, email, outlook, attachment

I have code to save all attachments in a specific folder.

When I run it on a selected email, I get an error due to Outlook.MailItem being empty.

Does this need a modification to work with selected items instead of an email fetched by a rule?

```vb
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk2(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim saveFolder As String

    Set Totalmsg = itm.ReceivedTime

    saveFolder = "C:\path\to\file"
     
    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
          objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & Totalmsg & "." & objAtt.DisplayName
          Set objAtt = Nothing
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This routine cannot work on its own.  It needs another routine to select `itm` and then call this routine.  You say "I simply try to select an email, and run it"; how do you select an email?  In answer to your final question: no, this routine can be used by any calling routine that passes an `MailItem`.  Where is `Totalmsg` declared?  `Totalmsg` does not sound like a variable holding a date.  Please use meaningful names.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Outlook, is it possible to run a macro on an email I select manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25315291/in-outlook-is-it-possible-to-run-a-macro-on-an-email-i-select-manually)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
      If Not objAtt Is Nothing Then
          objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & Totalmsg & "." & objAtt.DisplayName
      End If
Next
```

Note: There's no need to `Set objAtt = Nothing` for objAtt will be assigned a new value in the next loop and/or released at all when exiting sub.

Comment: I do not agree with "There's no need to `Set objAtt = Nothing` for objAtt".  `objAtt` has been passed `ByRef` (default) so this is clearing the `objAtt` for the caller.  This routine does not know if the caller has finished with `objAtt`.  I would say: "You MUST NOT set `objAtt` to `Nothing`.

Comment: @Tony Dallimore - here is right, there is absolutely no need to set objAtt to Nothing in this case: VBA releases all variables when they go out of scope (when the sub exits in this instance). In this particular case, "for each" loops keep all collection items referenced until the loop exits, so setting it inside the loop makes no difference. If you are processing a large number of items, it is better to use a "for" loop from 1 to Count, retrieve the item explicitly using Attachment.Item(i), then setting it explicitly to Nothing would actually work.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the `itm` variable  by setting it to `Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)` (error checking omitted)